# jquery knob not updating via webbsockets

Tags: jquery, websocket, jquery-knob, round-slider

I am getting the knob value via websockets and am able to display the value on the html page via document.elementId..
However I then try to update the knob based on this value and it does not occur

```
    <table id="speedTable">
        <tr>
            <td>revolutions</td></tr>
            <tr><td id="revolutions"></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="text" class="dial" id="revdial" value="0" data-width="120" data-thickness="0.4" >

</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.dial').knob({
        'min': 0,
            'max': 100,
            'step': 1,
            'readOnly': false,
            'linecap': 'round',
            'displayInput': true,
        'displayPrevious': false,
            'angleOffset': -125,
            'angleArc': 250
    });

    $('#revolutions).trigger('configure', {
        'draw': function (v) {
            v=parseInt(document.getElementById('revolutions').value);

            if (v > 2050 ) {
                this.o.fgColor='red';
                $("#revdial").css("color", "red");

            }
            if (v <= 2030 ) {
                this.o.fgColor='#87CEEB';
                $("#revdial").css("color", "#87CEEB");
                           }
            if (v > 2000  && v<=2030) {
                this.o.fgColor='#87CEEB';
                $("#revdial").css("color", "#87CEEB");

            }
        },
        'format': function (v) {
            return v + ' %';
        }
    });
    $('#revdial').trigger('change');
});
```

Please help. thank you

Comment: Are you need to use jquery knob only or any other alternative plugin can be used ?

Comment: any plugin can be used

Comment: Have you seen my below answer ? Is this suitable for you or anything was missed ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments i have prepared a demo similar to your requirement based on [jQuery roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin. Please check the below demo, it can be further customizable based on your requirement.

### [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/269/)

For more details check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.